# Getting list of MySQL Databases without logging in

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, c++11

I'm working on a Qt/C++ open source project that uses MySQL databases. One class will be used during initial configuration (first run) where the user will be able to select a database. Is there a way to provide a list of all databases on a host without logging in and executing a *SHOW DATABASES;* transaction? I want to get  a list of *all* databases on the host, not just those owned by a particular user. The only way I know of to do this is to execute *SHOW DATABASES;* as root on a specific host, but I don't want to require the user to have root access except in certain situations where it is absolutely necessary.

The idea is to have a dialog that lets the user select the default database they want to use during subsequent sessions and provide the user/pass that goes with it. Bonus points if I can get the owner of each database too. (for instance, have the program display that database *foo* is owned by johndoe while database *foo2* is owned by janesmith)  Once the user has made a choice, the dialog will then write this info to that user's program configuration file which gets read on normal startup.

Can this be done or will I have to find some workaround such as making the user provide a login/password first and showing a list of databases owned by that account? That would be relatively cumbersome but easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can't* execute MySql queries without logging in. That said it is possible to create a user which has very minimal privileges.

You can create a user with just enough privileges to show the list of databases and run the query as that user, then when the user has logged in change the connection string.

There is a `SHOW DATABASES` grant which allows just that : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-databases

Answer (score 0):

Normally you define a user for the application with read-only privileges and after fetching the information needed you present it to the user and then ask for his credentials. I'm just oversimplifying and not going over the specifics of how this is done.